# python translating strings, and changing them back using dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary, translate

I've got this code that translates a string (that starts out as a list) using a dictionary. I wanted the code to translate the string, then un-translate it back to the original.

This is the code that I've got so far:

```
words = ['Abra', ' ', 'cadabra', '!']
clues = {'A':'Z', 'a':'z', 'b':'y', 'c':'x'}
def converter(words, clues):
    words = ''.join(words)
    for item in words:
        if item in clues.keys():
            words = words.replace(item, clues[item])
    return words
def reversal(clues):
    clues = {v: k for k, v in clues.items()}
    print(clues)
x = converter(words, clues)
print(x)
reversal(clues)
x = converter(words, clues)
print(x)
```

Only, this will print
"Zyrz xzdzyrz!"
"Zyrz xdzyrz!"
I'm not sure why it's not printing:
"Zyrz xzdzyrz!"
"Abra cadabra!"

Is there an error in my code that is causing it to act this way? I checked clues and it IS reversed properly after it goes through the function. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to do a dictionary operation in place within a function. Your function needs to return the reversed version of the dictionary which you then need to pick up in your main:

```
# Your stuff here

def reversal(clues):
    return {v: k for k, v in clues.items()}

x = converter(words, clues)
print(x)
clues_reversed = reversal(clues)
x = converter(words, clues_reversed)
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python already has the `translate` method on all strings, just call it!

```
def converter(text, clues, reverse=False):
    if reverse:
        clues = {v: k for k, v in clues.items()}
    table = str.maketrans(clues)
    return text.translate(table)
```

Usage:

```
words = ['Abra', ' ', 'cadabra', '!']
clues = {'A':'Z', 'a':'z', 'b':'y', 'c':'x'}

# join the text into a single string:
x = ''.join(words)

# convert first
x = converter(x, clues)
print(x) # -> you get `Zyrz xzdzyrz!`

#back to original
x = converter(x, clues, reverse=True) 
print(x) # -> you get `Abra cadabra!`
```